# Encrypt password C# Decrypt Node.js

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, encryption, cryptography

I have a desktop application made in **C#**, and a web application with **node.js**. In the **C#** application I create users and from the web I have to login with those users. What I want is to **encrypt** the **password** from the c # app and save it to sql server and when the web client logs in that their password is encrypted and compared with the password from the database.

I've followed several tutorials, but I can not figure out how to do this.

What I have achieved so far is to save the password as bytes in the c # application but I do not know how to convert it to string and uncrypt it in node.js

I have also been able to encrypt the password in the web application as follows:

```
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('8080808080808080');
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('8080808080808080');

  var encryptedpassword = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse($('#input_password').val()), key, {
      keySize: 128 / 8,
      iv: iv,
      mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
      padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
  });
```

Crypt password in c#:

```
    public static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes(string plainText, byte[] key, byte[] iv) {

      // Check arguments.
      if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
      }
      if (key == null || key.Length <= 0) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
      }
      if (iv == null || iv.Length <= 0) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
      }
      byte[] encrypted;
      // Create a RijndaelManaged object
      // with the specified key and IV.
      using (var rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged()) {
        rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        rijAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        rijAlg.FeedbackSize = 128;

        rijAlg.Key = key;
        rijAlg.IV = iv;

        // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
        var encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

        // Create the streams used for encryption.
        using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream()) {
          using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)) {
            using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt)) {
              //Write all data to the stream.
              swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
            }
            encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
          }
        }
      }

      // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
      return encrypted;
    }
```

Encrypt password and save in sql server:

```
  Byte keybytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("8080808080808080");
  var iv = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("8080808080808080");
  user.password = AESEncrytDecry.EncryptStringToBytes(textEditPassword.Text, keybytes, iv);
//... save in sql
```

Can someone explain to me how to do this process?

Comment: *Hashing* passwords is much more secure, easy to manage & far simpler to get working across different platforms.

Comment: thank for your response @AlexK. can you show me a short example please?

Comment: What is the use of encrypting a password if you're decrypt it later anyway?

Comment: `I do not know how to convert it to string and uncrypt it in node.js` you **should not** convert it into a string, its binary data. also please post C# code

Comment: Thank you @Sharky. I idited the question with c# code

Comment: You should never encrypt your user's passwords. You need to use hashing instead with some strong ones being PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt and Argon2. Since hash functions are one-way function, you won't be able to "decrypt" the hashes. In order to authenticate your user, you can run the password through the hash function again in order to compare with the hash that is stored in the database. See more: [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523)